# How to get the IID_TOKEN for Google Instance ID service?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to register a topic with FCM using the below code. As per my understanding i need two Keys to register, first is IID_TOKEN and second is FCM_APP_KEY.

I have FCM_APP_KEY, but I am unable to find the cosole or site from where i can get the Google Instance ID service token(IID_TOKEN).

It will be of great help if someone one can tell the process or site to get the IID_TOKEN. Thanks in advance.

```
https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/IID_TOKEN/rel/topics/TOPIC
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=FCM_APP_KEY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to register a topic.

Topics are automatically created when the application calls

```
FirebaseCloudMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("topic-name")
```

The API you mentioned in the question is used when you have the
FirebaseInstanceId token of an (mobile / client) application
(obtained via `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()`) and you want to subscribe that application to a specific topic from your server side, instead of calling the `subscribeToTopic(..)` method mentioned above in the client.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i agree with you, but i have added dependency firebase-admin-sdk in my java web project but i can't find FirebaseInstanceId class. How can i get the token from my java web project? Is there some other dependency i need to add to my project?

Comment: FirebaseInstanceId is used to get the token of mobile / client app, not for your server app. Server app cannot receive FCM messages, so it doesn't make sense to subscribe the server app to a topic.

Comment: Ok, so when the client will register for the FCM from the web page and it will get the token by calling messaging.getToken() is the IID_TOKEN and then using the same i will be able to register for a topic and if the topic is not  present it will be created.Please correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: Correct. note that the web page needs to send iid-token to your server. Then your server can call the api you wrote above with it's FCM_APP_KEY and the IID-TOKEN of the webpage.

Comment: The documentation at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging uses `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("topic-name");`, not `FirebaseCloudMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("topic-name")`. Why do you use `FirebaseCloudMessaging` instead of `FirebaseMessaging`? Is there a difference?